# Application Variable in SQLDataSource control parameter

Tags: asp.net, .net, sqldatasource, css

Perhaps this is laziness on my part, but in the same way I can reference a connection string from my web.config using `<%$ ConnectionStrings:con %>`, I'd like to do similar referencing an Application variable in one of my select parameters.  Something like:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="AppVal" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="<% Application['MyVal'] %>" />
```

Is this stupid of me?  Should I just shut up and set the parameter value in the codebehind?  I've been Googling for hours trying to describe the different ways to leverage the angle-bracket-percent-sign style tags in ASP.Net and have only found inline code and code render blocks (<%=), as well as data binding (<%#).  What's this <%$ all about, and are there others I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I see now that the `<%$` references an ExpressionBuilder.  Using some handy code I was able to create my own ApplicationExpressionBuilder and populate the desired value into my control.

Google Custom Session Expression Builder to find code for a similar way to leverage session variables and make the easy switch over to application variables if it suits you.